# When you don't understand a joke right away

Tags: word-request, idioms, jokes

In my native language we have lots of ways (some of them very funny) of saying that you, or someone else didn't understand a joke right away. That is, he/she needed some time to figure it out.

I wonder if there's any idiomatic way of expressing that in English.

Comment: One that's used often in UK and AU when someone doesn't get something at all (not restricted to a joke) is: *"That went right over his/her/their head"*

Comment: Some people call these [joke grenades](http://www.myspace.com/video/vid/8825400) (~1:36)  where you tell them, and then wait for several seconds for people to get them and start to laugh.

Comment: It's not quite the same thing, but "whoosh!" is the sound of a joke going over someone's head.

Comment: @snailplane: Those two are very much related. However, "whoosh!" requires the hearer to already be familiar with the idiom "over his head;" otherwise, that onomatopoeia will go, well, right over the hearer's head :^)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The word **get** is particularly used these days in the context of understanding jokes - and even more particularly in the negative, for *not* understanding. With no other context...

> *"I don't get it", "He doesn't get it!", "Don't you get it?",* etc.

...are very likely to be assumed to be in reference to [a joke that wasn't understood](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doesn%27t%20get%20the%20joke,doesn%27t%20see%20the%20joke,doesn%27t%20understand%20the%20joke&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

[image]

Comment: +1 For both the most universally understandable phrase (probably understood in UK and US English), and for one that,  more than the others, is specific to "getting a joke".

Comment: @David: ty. Actually, the answer itself isn't intended to be a joke, but *somebody* didn't "get" it (I got an anonymous downvote! :)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGzCjxvoJNI watch from 0.45 to hear the expression: "I don't get it" in its context.

Answer (score 12):

The first phrase that comes to mind is '[The penny dropped'](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-penny-dropped?showCookiePolicy=true). As with jwpat7's suggestion, this phrase is not limited to understanding a joke, but is commonly used in that sense.

Particularly in a situation where a lot of people have been laughing at a joke and I finally understand it, I would say:

> "Ah, the penny just dropped!"

Comment: Nice idiomatic expression! But you don't often hear it used in the negative for when the penny *hasn't* dropped - except when followed by *yet*, with the strong implication that it soon will.

Comment: I'd not even thought of the negative usage for some reason. I feel that 'Waiting for the penny to drop' is moderately common, though perhaps that is a NZ English peculiarity - seems likely that this depends a lot on very localised culture such as television programs.

Comment: In my language if someone doesn't get something, we say _his/her penny is bent_ (so it's stuck and is likely to not drop).

Answer (score 10):

You may hear *over his/her head*.

> That one went over his head.

While it applies more to someone who is not familiar enough with English or the appropriate cultural/topical reference to get the joke, rather than someone who is just *slow on the uptake*, it's just as likely to happen in an ELL setting as the latter.

It can also be expressed by simply waving your hand over your head and making an apologetic expression.

Comment: +1: As with *penny dropped*, this one is a common idiomatic expression (an equivalent is *That one **passed him by***).

Answer (score 9):

The phrase *[slow on the uptake](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/slow-on-the-uptake)*, often is so used.  As seen from the examples at Collins Dictionary, it does not specifically refer to being slow to understand a joke, but I've often heard it used that way.

Comment: Related: “dawn comes late in some countries”.

Answer (score 3):

If your <s>auditory</s> audience are active Web users, they may be aware about an Internet [meme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme), **Slowpoke**.

[image: Slowpoke]
<sup>image from [here](http://memegenerator.net/instance/18418572)</sup>

[Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=slowpoke) defines *slowpoke* as *"An unnecessarily slow person, not mentally, just physically."*

There's also a [Pokémon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowpoke_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) with the same name.

Hence, this term is often used on Internet boards to denote a person who's too slow to get a joke.

By the way, it can be also used if someone is posting an old joke that was popular a while ago, and everyone already knows it.

Comment: I do not think this is a useful word for someone learning English if they're not already encountering it. In which case they would know it, or easily be able to look it up.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The Internet memes are essential part of the language. An English learner is **already exposed to memes** within StackExchange network. See [do you haz teh codez?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13231/what-does-do-you-haz-teh-codez-mean).

Comment: @StoneyB Audience, of course. This pair of words is hard for me all times.

Comment: Like I say, if a learner encounters *slowpoke* in other contexts, they'll easily see what it means - either from context, or by looking it up somewhere like urbandict. But ("meme" or not) it isn't a "core" English word (I don't know any related terms except *cowpoke*). Sooner or later I suppose we'll have to thrash out on meta whether this sort of thing is what we want on ELL.

Comment: @bytebuster  "Auditory", as a noun, is in fact the old word, and I was excited to see you revive it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I concur. It may be a large part of a scope since people already use it, but some may think it's not for the learners. Likewise any idiomatic constructs.

Comment: @StoneyB In my language, _auditory_ means group of listeners (or classroom) while _audience_ means a formal meeting.

Comment: @bytebuster: Even if the actual word *auditory* exists in your language, it's certainly not used by Anglophones in your context here.

Comment: Worth noting that *slowpoke* isn’t a new word; it’s attested back to at least 1848, [according to Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=Slowpoke), and was reasonably common in my childhood (UK, 80’s/90’s).

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "late to the punchline" is idiomatic, and always refers to this situation.