# What does "thank you for getting it" mean in daily English?

Tags: meaning

My question is about "getting it". Does it mean to thank sb. for his attaining sth.? Or, does it mean to thank sb. for settling sth.？Or, to thank sb. for understanding eth.?

Comment: Maybe you could add some more context? "Getting it" could mean "understanding it". Or just "Oh, thank you for getting my scarf from the shelf and bringing it to me." (Here's sour scarf, dear. - Oh, thank you for getting it.)

Comment: In the absence of further context from OP, this looks like a duplicate of [***get = understand** {a joke, an explanation, etc.}*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/1152/126)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Getting it** is basically **get**, with a noun (*it* or *other things*). **Get** can mean receive, acquire, understand, etc.

Check this link for the definition of the word **get**:
https://www.google.com/search?q=define+get

---

So, **thank you for getting it** could mean **thank you for understanding**, et cetera., depending on the context.